# Xcode display asset icon filename in code editor

Tags: xcode, editor, assets

Is there anyway to show an assets icon image and its file name? I've seen it in videos but I can't seem to get it to display in my code editor.

This is what I get:

[image]

And this is what I want: 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It used to be this way in Xcode 8, the name would be displayed alongside the image. In Xcode 9 the name has been removed and this behavior does not seem to be customizable.

Comment: That sounds incredibly inconvenient, especially in the case where the text background is dark and makes images hard to see.

Answer (score 2):

simply comment the line and you'll see the image resource name.
[image]
[image]